# Change font size/font family midway through content:

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi everyone I have a small question, is it possible to change this?

Is it possible to make "MY NAME IS" a different font family and size? and keep "jane citizen" as the Regular font family?
This is my css

```
  .header .Heading2.flex-row.first.ab:after {
    font-family: Regular;
    font-size:10px;
    content: 'MY NAME IS \A jane\A citizen';
    white-space: pre-wrap;
  }
```

Comment: You can try this - <div class="class1">MY NAME IS </div><div class="class2">jane citizen</div>

Answer (score 0):

You can try `:after` & `:before`

```css
.header:before {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size:10px;
    content: 'MY NAME IS ';
    white-space: pre-wrap;
  }
.header:after {
    font-family: Regular;
    font-size:10px;
    content: 'jane citizen';
    white-space: pre-wrap;
  }
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
```